# RESTful API for serving videos to a client

Tags: javascript, mvc, node.js, express.js

I'm building an app that serves videos to a front end client. My stack is Express/Angular/SQLite. The db doesn't hold users, only root. I'm concerned that my controllers are too hardcoded, but I'm wary of the balance between making controllers *too* dynamic such that I'm merely pigeonholing myself into an over-engineered framework.

Backend project structure:

```
/server

    app.js                           //creates app-wide express instance and feeds necessary dependencies to child components

    /config
        db.auth.js                   //for sqlite
        paths.js                     //references to location of videos and other assets
        routes.js                    //defines the api the frontend requests

     /controllers

        /recipes
            doSomethingRedundant.js  //many controller methods require this
            index.js                 //exports all recipes

        index.js                     //exports all controllers
        videoController.js           //methods for Video model
        peopleController.js          //methods for Person model
        playlistController.js        //methods for Playlist model
        //etc.

    /database
        sequelize.bootstrap.js       //returns single app-wide instance of db connection
        sqlite.db                    //database

    /middleware
        static.js                    //defining paths to static file locations
        webhooks.js                  //other stuff, like build

    /models
        index.js                     //exports models for easy access to controllers
        Video.js
        Person.js
        Studio.js
        //etc

    /services
        index.js                      //main exporter
        makeReel.js                   //makes preview strip via ffmpeg

    /views
        index.html                    //frontend is SPA, there is only one view, basically
```

I'm content with this structure. It's easy for me to understand and I know where everything is supposed to go. But, here's what my `routes.js` file looks like:

```
var controllers = require("./../controllers/index.js");

module.exports = function(app) {
    //this seems suspicious, but I can't explain lucidly why it feels wrong
    app.get("/videos/:range/some", controllers.videos.getSome); 
    app.get("/videos/:id/one", controllers.videos.getOne);
    app.get("/videos/:id/random", controllers.videos.getRandom);

    app.get("/thumbs/:video/:thumb", controllers.images.getOne);
    app.get("/thumbs/:video/range/:range", controllers.images.getMany);
};
```

And the video controller:

```
var async = require("async");
var path = require("path");
var _ = require("lodash");
var util = require("./../services/util.js");
var bootstrap = require("./../database/sequelize.bootstrap.js");
var sequelize = bootstrap.sequelize;
var models = bootstrap.models;
var recipes = bootstrap.recipes;

module.exports = {
    getAll: function(req, res) {
        models.Video.findAll()
            .then(function(rows) {
                res.send(getval(rows));
            })
            .catch(util.err);
    },
    getSome: function(req, res) {
        var range = req.params.id.split(",");
        models.Video.findAll({
            where: {
                id: {
                    $between: [range[0], range[1]]
                }
            }
        }).then(function(rows) {
            res.send(getval(rows));
        }).catch(util.err)
    },

    //get the video ID and all associated model instances
    getOne: function(req, res) {
        recipes.getVideoInfo(req.params.id, function(result) {
            res.send(result);
        });
    },
    getRandom: function(req, res) {
        models.Video.count().then(function(count) {

            (function ran(except, range) {
                var r = _.random(0, range);
                if (r === except)
                    return ran(except);
                recipes.getVideoInfo(r, function(result) {
                    res.send(result);
                });
            })(req.params.id, count);

        }).catch(util.err);
    }
};

function getval(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(obj) {return obj.dataValues;});
}
```

I feel I'm committing a cardinal sin by splitting up a similar `GET` request for video info into several similar `getRandom`, `getOne`, `getSome`, `getAll` methods. Is this a bad idea? Due to lack of experience I can't really tell.